# How do I add a link from a Calendar entry to a Contact entry?

Tags: contacts, 2.3-gingerbread, hardware, calendar

I have a calendar entry and want to have a link to a specific phone number in my Contacts list.  The Calendar, Contacts and phone apps are the built-in apps.

Specifically I want to have the Calendar alert allow me to click the "reorder" phone number entry for my pharmacy contact and it will dial.  That's the 2nd phone # for that contact and has all the responses and pauses to reorder a script.

Samsung SGH-I927 Captivate Glide
Android 2.3.6
Kernel 2.6.36.3
Build Gingerbread UCKL1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a newer version of Android/device or at least a more capable calendar app that can run on Gingerbread. The modern stock version of the Calendar (I think from 4.0 onward) lets you assign people from your contacts to appointments. Only about 4% of Android users are currently running Gingerbread so you're kind of in a small minority and may not find much help because so few of us are running anything earlier than Android 4.0.

Comment: Thx for the info.  I wish I *could* upgrade.  This model updates the OS via a Windows prog that doesn't run (for me).